# execute .exe file from local website

Tags: php, html

I'm making an application in html/php to serve as an information (touch) panel for clients of the camping I work at. The website will be hosted only on the local machine with no web access to it trough XAMPP for windows (the computer is running windows XP)

So I need to add a button that opens an external application that allows clients to turn on the electricity for their camping pitches. They can then close the external application and they will be retuned to the website (web app or whatever you want to call it) which is running in the background on fullscreen mode (you know, when you press F11 in your browser)

Is this at all possible? if so, how?

Comment: If opting for the `exec` solution, pay attention to the first warning in the notes of the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php) if any user defined data is being passed. It doesn't sound like it in this case but better to mention it just in case

Comment: @Drizien, if one of the answers worked for you, you should accept it so that other's looking at the answers will know what works.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `exec`, which will run a command in cmd.

So if your file is at c:, you'll just run `C:\file.exe`

Read more about http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php

Answer (score 0):

Use `exec`

Example from [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php):

```
<?php
// outputs the username that owns the running php/httpd process
// (on a system with the "whoami" executable in the path)
echo exec('whoami');
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yup [exec](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php) is what you need to look at.